# How to combine output of an app with usb microphone for recording?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, external-soundcard

I want to use my USB microphone in voice chats (discord, teamspeak, skype etc.)

But I also want to occasionaly include the sound of another app, e.g. firefox youtube playback

So when I push-to-talk not only my voice but also sound of my apps should be transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually I decided to create two virtual sinks:

- "record_as_input" which all my apps route their audio to, but it will also be routed to my main soundcard so I can still hear the apps
- "combined_input" which combines record_as_input(apps) and my microphone(my voice)

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name="combined_input" sink_properties=device.description="combined_input"

pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name="record_as_input" sink_properties=device.description="record_as_input"
```

So I can still hear the audio:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source=record_as_input.monitor sink=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
```

Route the recorded apps to the combined sink:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source=record_as_input.monitor sink=combined_input
```

Route the mic to the combined sink:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.usb-AKM_AK5370-00.mono-fallback sink=combined_input
```

Change the default source so that programs like Discord can use the Default input device:

```
pacmd set-default-source combined_input.monitor
```

You can find your sources and sinks with:

```
pactl list short sources
pactl list short sinks
```

Now you need to route the audio with pavucontrol as follows:

```
Loopback from Monitor of record_as_input -> Your main output/speakers
Loopback from Monitor of record_as_input -> combined_input
Loopback from AK5370 I/F A/D Mono (your microphone) -> combined_input
Firefox (or any other app) -> record_as_input
```

If you no longer need an app to be mixed into your default input, then change it back to your main output/speakers.

To make the settings permanent I've added the above commands (without pactl/pacmd) to the end of /etc/pulse/default.pa